# SMS Verification Code from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to know if it is possible to change the text of the verification SMS that is sent from Firebase with a code to login in an android application

Comment: no you cannot change the text

Comment: but you can change the language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is currently not possible. I am not quite sure why, but the Firebase team does currently not intent to change that (I think), user have asked about this for a long time, but it never changed.

Though as [Salman500](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7941229/salman500) pointed out, you can head over to `Authentication` **->** `TEMPLATES` in your Firebase Console and change the template language.

[image: Screenshot of Authentication tab in Firebase Console]

I think it used to be possible to change the templates, at least the password reset mail, but their statement to why it is not possible was "*spam prevention*".

For custom, in this example *welcome* and *bye* message, e-mails you can use this [Cloud Functions for Firebase example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users). It is obviously fully customizable.

I think that the missing support for proper verification, I mean at least language locale should be support, is a shame and will support this opinion in the future. I think this answer is disappointing for you, but at least you know.

Comment: haha.. yeah, I am a little upset with the results. I was trying to customize the message because it is a little confusing to the user to understand that the SMS is related to the application. Thanks for the answers, I think I will try the Cloud Functions with the emails